# Loop through string and look for certain characters in shell

Tags: bash, shell

lets say I have the following string stored in a variable:

string="1245aaa./ ssasaaa* kjdsaaa"

Is there a way to somehow loop through this string and find out that it contains 3 "words" so to speak separated by blank spaces and that the word with the most "a" is the second one and there are total of 4 "a" in the second word?

I've been trying to google something like this but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method is grepping for the line with at least n (in your example 4) `a`'s.
First you must find the number you need to grep for.
In steps (requested in comment):
Split the words in the string into lines by replacing (`tr`, translate) spaces with newlines.

```
echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n"
```

With `sed 's/old/new/g'` you can s (substitute) the old string (pattern) with the new string g (globally). So you can `echo "Have all characters a banned" | sed 's/a//g'`. You want to replace all characters except for the character a. The `^` in `[^a]` stands for `not`, the `[]` for a class of characters.

```
echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/[^a]//g'
```

You can find the longest string of a's by sorting them. After sorting, the last line will have most. With `tail -1` you get the last line:

```
echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/[^a]//g'|sort | tail -1
```

Now put the result in a variable. You can assign the output of another (set of) unix command(s) to a variable with `var=$(command)`, be aware that you do not add spaces around the `=` sign (`var = $(xxx)` will fail).

```
most_a=$(echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n" | sed 's/[^a]//g'|sort | tail -1)
```

When you want to see the contents of a variable, use `$var` or prefer `${var}`. With `{}` everybody knows that the `other_chars` in `${var}other_chars` are not part of the variable name. With an `#` in `${#var}` you ask for a number of chars. And always use double quotes when using echo until you understa

```
echo "The word with the highest number of a's has ${#most_a} of those"
```

Now you can grep the word with this number of a's out of a list of words. When you want to grep strings with at least 4 a's you will need `.*` (any character repeated 0 or more times), so grep for `a.*a.*a.*a` or `a.*a.*a.*a.*`. You can tell grep that the pattern `(a.*)` is repeated `{4}` or `{${#most_a}}` times.
Now you need some backslashes to activate the special meaning of the `(){}` characters and start splitting the original string in words:

```
echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n" | grep "\(a.*\)\{${#most_a}\}"
```

To print the string and number, use something like

```
printf "%s %s\n" ${#most_a} $(echo "${string}" | tr " " "\n" | grep "\(a.*\)\{${#most_a}\}" )
```

Comment: Thank you. The first bit of the code is executing the functionality I was looking for. Could you please give a bit of explanation on the commands used? I would really appreciate that as it would save me a lot of time trying to google and figure out what exactly they all mean in this context. Especially this part:  tr " " "\n" | sed 's/[^a]//g'|sort | tail -1)

Comment: Updated my answer. Try each line.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is exactly what I needed : )

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can handle this:

```
string="1245aaa./ ssasaaa* kjdsaaa"

awk -v k='a' -v RS=' ' '{n = split($0, a, k)-1} 
     n > max{max=n; maxw=$0} END{print maxw, max}' OFS=, <<< "$string"
```

**Output:**

```
ssasaaa*,4
```

Comment: I've made a minor change to make it work for both gnu and non-gnu (BSD) awk

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I do have a few questions, on the last line  n > max{max=n; maxw=$0} END{print maxw, max}' OFS=, <<< "$string", Im getting syntax error: redirection unexpected. Also could you please elaborate a bit on what exactly the code {n = split($0, a, k)-1}  as well as the last line mean? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You may have done some copy/paste error. [You can see in this demo how this awk command is working fine](http://ideone.com/OC5RfU). To run this awk in single line use: **`awk -v k='a' -v RS=' ' '{n = split($0, a, k)-1} n > max{max=n; maxw=$0} END{print maxw, max}' OFS=, <<< "$string"`**. `split` function splits an entry by given letter `a` and returns # of elements in output array.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do this in Bash alone.

Given:

```
$ string="1245aaa./ ssasaaa* kjdsaaa"
```

You can break that string into 'words' by breaking on the current IFS into an array:

```
$ words=( $string )
```

Then loop over each word and count the regex matches:

```
$ for word in "${words[@]}"
> do
> printf "%i %s\n" $(egrep -o 'a' <<<$word | wc -l) $word 
> done
3 1245aaa./
4 ssasaaa*
3 kjdsaaa
```

And pipeline the result of that into `sort` to sort by match count and `head` to get the top one:

```
for word in "${words[@]}"
do
    printf "%i %s\n" $(egrep -o 'a' <<<$word | wc -l) $word 
done | sort -n -r | head -1
4 ssasaaa*
```

`awk` is more efficient, but you can do this way too.

Answer (score 0):

```
 string="1245aaa./ ssasaaa* kjdsaaa"

 echo $string | tr ' ' '\n' | while read s
 do  
 echo "`echo $s | tr -dc 'a' | wc -c` $s"
 done | sort -nr
```

or

```
echo $string | xargs -n 1 bash -c 'for s; do echo "`echo $s | tr -dc 'a' | wc -c` $s"; done' bash | sort -nr
```